# Can I change a variable link to another symbol over ADS?

Tags: plc, twincat, structured-text, twincat-ads

Using TwinCAT 3.
I'm using a function block like `MC_Home`. I would like to set/change the link/pointer/something else clever to where `MC_Home` should read its input `bCalibrationCam` from.
I would like to set this from my other application over ADS when the PLC is running. I will do it before starting actual execution of the `MC_Home`.

Example: This execution I would like that `MC_Home` uses a symbol called `bHome1`. Next execution maybe the symbol to be used by `MC_Home` could be `bSomeVeryDifferentSensor39`.

One thing I have tried is using a pointer. Setting the adress of the pointer over ADS and then dereferencing it in `MC_Home`. This works great, but I have one problem. I'm unable from the ADS side to know the PLC adress of my symbols. I manually used the supplied function block `ADR`, read out the PLC memory adress of my symbol and entered that for the pointer.
However, I'm unable to find the PLC memory adress of symbols over ADS. I can of course find the index group and index offset of my symbols using ADS, but this seems to not correlate to the PLC memory adress that the FB `ADR` supplies in a way that I can understand.

Another thing that would work is this: I could create a function block that accepted a symbol name (string?) as input and ran `ADR` on that variable and gave me the resulting adresss back, but I'm not sure if it is possible to create such a function block.

Comment: Why wouldn't you make an `enum` and define members. Then, from outside, just set the `enum` value of the variable to the one you need and inside your code make a case statement that switches the `MC_Home.bCalibrationCam := <value in this case>; ` This way no "woodo" is happening in your code, and you are 100% sure what is happening.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to the same problem. In my case, we use a library, so where the needed variables aren't even available. It also seems like a very rigid solution. 
You would also need a maping from the ENUM values to the variables in the other application.

Comment: Hello Dean, I'm happy to hear other users are facing similar problems. From our ADS side applicaiton we know the symbol name that we want to use. But we would prefer to  not change our customers PLC projects and map up all the digital inputs that exist into a switch statement.